# How to dynamically include libs in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, dll, tesseract

I followed [this](https://vorba.ch/2014/tesseract-3.03-vs2013.html) guide to compile the debug DLLs for tesseract

Now I got the DDLs to include in my project. So I added the lib directory in `linker/lib` dir, the lib name in `linker/input` and in `include` dir I put the location of `"baseapi.h"`. So I included in my project "baseapi.h".

However I get compile errors when I try for example to compile the following line:

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *myOCR = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
```

I get a lot of errors like IntelliSense:

```
variable "tesseract::TESS_LOCAL" 
IntelliSense: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier.
```

The files are the following:

[image]

Comment: Well your description is not very helpful: (1) Only compile errors matter, IntelliSense could lag (2) Try to make complete example. While usually people post too much code you are one the opposite site with too little code shown. And also make sure you `#include` all required headers.

Comment: As an aside, why are you using pointers?

Comment: This problem is specific to libtesseract, yet your question title is extraordinarily generic. Please make it describe the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the library's code, `TESS_LOCAL` is a macro used before several function definitions inside `api/baseapi.h`, which is defined in `ccutil/platform.h`.

If you'd simply followed [the instructions](https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/git/vs2008/doc/programming.html), you'd have seen that you need to:

> include Leptonica’s allheaders.h, and Tesseract-OCR’s baseapi.h and strngs.h.

This will pull in what you need.

Comment: I though was a linking problem, probably I linked well. I contacted him, I don't think I'm going to get an answer.

Comment: @alteration: Just follow the instructions...